# How to add element at specific index/position in HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have some HashSet collection of String elements, how I can add new element at specific position? I saw documentation and didn't find any method that can do it.

Comment: One of the aspects of a *hash*set is that it is **unordered**.

Comment: How do you *access* the element at a specific position?

Comment: using Iterator or foreach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the aspects of a *standard* [**`HashSet<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is that it **is unordered**. So you cannot insert an element at a specific index. Or as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the `Set` interface, backed by a hash table (actually a `HashMap` instance). It makes **no guarantees as to the iteration order** of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the `null` element.

When you do an insertion, deletion, etc. it is possible that the `HashSet<T>` will do a *rehashing*. As a result the order of the elements in a `for(...)` loop can change *completely*.

There exists an *extension* of a `Hashset<T>`, the [**`LinkedHashSet<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which maintains the order of the elements in which they were *inserted*.

A [**`TreeSet<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) on the other hand, uses a tree, and orders the elements according to an order relation (an object that is less than another object, is emitted before that element).

It would be weird if you could insert an element at a random index, since that would result in *O(n)* time for at least some operations with a specific index. Usually one uses a `HashSet<T>` to perform insertions, removal, etc. in *O(1)* (average time).

Answer (score 0):

we can [see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW9CR.png)  use list to add at particular index and then add that list to set using object.addAll(listobject or setobject

```
Set<Integer> s=new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> s1=new HashSet<Integer>(); 
s1.add(6);
List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(5);
l.add(2,2);
l.add(0);
System.out.println(l);
S.addAll(l);//list
S.addAll(s1);//another set
```